# View and PartialView with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I divide my space screen with a table in 2 columns. The left one is for the menu the right one for the content. In the right column I use jQuery UI tab. The second tab manage a list of contact, I divide the content of this second tab in 2 columns. The left one is the form to add/update a contact, in the right column it's a grid. The problem when I post the form is on "DetailContactDetail", i tried return View, PartialView, or I get the form full screen without anything. I'd like refresh the content of the tab to see the change in the grid.

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult DetailContact()
{
    ....
    return PartialView("DetailContact", model);
}

public ActionResult SaveContact(CustomerModel model)
{
    .....
    return PartialView("DetailContactDetail");
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<script id="Ready" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (e, ui) {
                runMethod(ui.index);
            }
        });
    });

    function runMethod(selectedtab) {
        switch (selectedtab) {
            case 0:
                $.post('/Customer/DetailGeneral', function (data) {
                    $('#tabs-1').html(data);
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                $.post('/Customer/DetailContact', function (data) {
                    $('#tabs-2').html(data);
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                $.post('/Customer/DetailAdresse', function (data) {
                    $('#tabs-3').html(data);
                });
                break;
        }
    }
</script>

<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
    <td style="width:20%;vertical-align:top;">                  
        @Html.Partial("MnuCustomer")
    </td>
    <td style="width:80%;vertical-align:top;">  
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Adress</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">@Html.Partial("DetailGeneral", Model)</div>
            <div id="tabs-2"></div>
            <div id="tabs-3"></div>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The tab content look like this (PartialView "DetailContact.cshtml") look like :

```
<table style="width:100%;" border="0">
<tr>
    <td style="width:50%;">@Html.Partial("DetailContactDetail",Model)</td>
    <td style="width:50%;">@Html.Partial("DetailContactGrid",Model)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

DetailContactDetail and DetailContactGrid are PartialView.

Comment: kris - i recognise that code :) - anyway, what is <script id="Ready". i've never seen a script attr like that... explain how that works plz. tho that said, i'm not sure i understand your question fully. is your DetailContactDetail post targetting any jquery code??

Comment: @Kris: Do you see any JavaScript errors on your page?

Comment: @Andrew I had a Javascript error, I removed the JS code .... same result.

Comment: @jim the javascript call here it's used to load the content of the tab (works fine). the tab content is divided in 2 parts, a form a partialview on the left with the form and a partialview on the right with the grid.  After the post I'd like keep the same screen :) not a blank page with DetailContactDetail

Comment: @Kris: Your code looks fine to me at a glance. If you use **only** this code on your page does it work?

Comment: Could you show your code in `DetailContactDetail`, in particular, how you handle the form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me you are not submitting the form via AJAX, which seemed like what you wanted to do. If you don't submit the form via AJAX, you should return the whole page (i.e. the page that you show code snippet), not just `PartialView("DetailContactDetail")`.

In another note, it seems to me that your code with tab can be vastly simplified to the following:

```
<script id="Ready" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

...

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Customer/DetailGeneral">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Customer/DetailContact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Customer/DetailAdresse">Adress</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```